# Does the size of the cone of a spot lamp have a meaning?

Tags: lighting

So the spot lamp has a cone which ends after a distance. Does the size of the cone hold any meaning? I tried scaling the spot lamp, which changes the size of the cone but doesn't seem to change the final render at all.
Additonally both the spot lamp and the area lamp have a line which indicates in which direction the lamps are facing. This lamp also ends after a certain distance and unlike the cone doesn't change it's size when scaling the lamps. Does the length of this cone hold any meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: comment indicates that the question was about the *length* of the cone.  That's entirely and only so you can visualize where the spotlight's light falls. It has no impact on the intensity of the light.

Old answer, for the *size* of the spot.

Here's a scene lit entirely by a spotlight.  We start with the "Spot Size", which is the size of the cone at 3.5 degrees:

[image: Suzanne with spot set at 3.5 degrees.]

10.5 degrees:

[image: Suzanne with spot set at 10.5 degrees.]

31.5 degrees:

[image: Suzanne with spot set at 21.5 degrees.]

As you can see, the size of the cone effects *where* the light shines.

Here are the same three settings, but in Solid shading mode and with Show Cone enabled:

[image: 3.5]

[image: 10.5]

[image: 31.5]

making it more obvious what's going on.

You can read more about the [Spot Lamp](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/lights/light_object.html#spot-light) in the manual.

Comment: It seems my question wasn't very clear. What I meant was the length of the cone not the angle.

Comment: @tempdevnova  No. The scale only helps you envision the conde.  It doesn't affect the light in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The smaller the lamp size, the sharper the shadows it casts. The bigger, the more blurred of a shadow.

Comment: OP is asking about the _cone_ from a spotlight; not the lamp itself.

Comment: Oh. Didn't catch that.